# Tunnel all traffic through SSH?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ssh

Given Windows 7 I want to tunnel all its network traffic through SSH, without manually tunnelling each port.  It's easy on Linux, but I couldn't find any hint on how to do this on Windows ): So, any hint on how this can be done on Windows 7?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way in Windows to change all applications' proxies at once. Many programs use the settings of IE though.

Comment: Hmm after thinking more about it: Shouldn't I be able to use VPN and tunnel this over SSH?

Comment: You can do that, but SSH VPNs aren't as good as "normal" (PPTP) VPNs. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)'s a complete setup guide for the latter.

Comment: Use the dynamic forwarding feature of SSH (-D option, opens a local SOCKS server) then setup a proxifier. This will however only work for TCP and not UDP or anything else. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

Comment: But... then SSH gets tunneled over SSH and your computer explodes! (results may vary)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. SSH uses TCP, so you end up with a [TCP over TCP problem](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html).

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Guess I should use OpenVPN (already uses TLS) instead of VPN over SSh.